# Using ArcGIS for Desktop when learning via QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, references

I'm currently trying to teach myself GIS.

I use a Mac and have limited access to ArcGIS for Desktop at a library, so I'm thinking about going the QGIS route.

My concern is that most job vacancies that are looking for a proficiency in GIS will be using ArcGIS for Desktop.

I'm not too familiar with either yet, so I'm wondering how different the program interfaces really are.

If I work on becoming proficient using QGIS, will I still be totally lost if I need to use ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Our protocols can take a little getting used to but I think your question falls out of scope (as defined in the help) because it is asking for opinions.  Nevertheless, my opinion is that if you know one or other well then you will find many familiar workflows in the other.  I speak as someone fluent in ArcGIS for Desktop and comfortable that I could adapt to QGIS.

Comment: ArcGIS home license (1 year) $100  http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home (for noncommercial personal use only.)

Comment: As your on a Mac (Intel processor) you will need parallels to run ArcGIS+Windows on your Mac. http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/